# "He disagreed with something that ate him." (spoilers)

Tags: idioms, register, cinema

In *The Living Daylights* (a James Bond film), there is a man named Felix Leiter who is [partially] eaten by a shark. The villain writes a paper that says: 'He disagreed with something that ate him.' Is this a common English idiom for use polite conversation, or is this informal slang?

Comment: The name is Felix. Felix Leiter http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Felix_Leiter The word *villain* http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/villain?q=villain would be a better choice than "bad man".

Comment: And it's a joke. Or what passes for a joke in a Bond movie. It's a takeoff on the common phrase "He ate something that disagreed with him", meaning he is sick because of eating something. In this case it's the other day around, and it's just strange enough that it takes the audience an extra beat to process it. This makes it a joke. Officially, at least.

Comment: You should have seen the headline they quashed: _Flex Lighter nearly stiffed._

Comment: Just in case others are misled: this is a joke/troll account that asks silly and deliberately disingenuous questions that nonetheless require a bit of lateral thinking to locate the actual jokes.

Comment: The quote "He disagreed with something that ate him" first appeared in the Ian Fleming novel "Live and Let Die", published in 1954. It refers to CIA agent Felix Leiter being fed to sharks by Mr. Big (but surviving, losing an arm and a leg).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a play on words, and not something you would expect to use in ordinary conversation.

You can find two senses of the phrasal verb *disagree with*:

> **[disagree with](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/disagree?q=disagree+with#disagree__9)**
> 1.1 Disapprove of:
>
> > she disagreed with the system of apartheid
>
> 2.1 (Of food, climate, or an experience) have an adverse effect on:
>
> > the sea crossing disagreed with her

The joke, then, is that the man did not eat shark, which then made him ill (sense #2), but that a shark ate him, which he found disagreeable (sense #1).

Comment: You wouldn't use it in ordinary conversation, but it's not impolite.

Comment: @KitFox Right, I only meant that if your conversation partners are losing limbs to animals frequently enough for you to whip out this quip on a regular basis, they should really converse less and focus on improving their situational awareness.

Answer (score 2):

The CIA agent’s name is Felix Leiter, and yes, there is an English idiom whereby food that causes indigestion is said to “disagree” with the eater. (Relative to some alternatives, such as “gave me the runs” or “made me hurl,” this idiom is *very* polite.) This idiom is the source of quite a number of lame jokes, such as the James Bond movie franchise has a weakness for. A variant is to say that the food “doesn’t like” the eater, as in the hoary old cannibal joke, “I like missionary, but missionary doesn’t like me.”